# SAPUI5 remove CSS class of aggregation items

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5

I have a xml view fragment which includes a side navigation

```
<SideNavigation id="sideNavigation" expanded="false">
    <item>
        <NavigationList expanded="false">
            <NavigationListItem text="Start" icon="sap-icon://employee" select="initChangeView" expanded="false">
            </NavigationListItem>
            <NavigationListItem text="On Track" icon="sap-icon://building" select="initChangeView" expanded="false">
            </NavigationListItem>
            <NavigationListItem text="Details" icon="sap-icon://employee" select="initChangeView" expanded="false">
            </NavigationListItem>
            <NavigationListItem text="Comparison" icon="sap-icon://employee" select="initChangeView" expanded="false">
            </NavigationListItem>
        </NavigationList>
    </item>

</SideNavigation>
```

I want to add and remove a custom css class when one is of the items is selected.
What I am trying to do is to remove the class "selectedNavItem" from every NavigationListItem and add it to the selected one, but I get the TypeError

> Cannot read property 'removeStyleClass' of undefined

Handler in controller.js:

```
jQuery.sap.require("xxx.controller.NavigationBar");
[...]
initChangeView: function(oEvent){  
        setExpandedToFalse(this);
        changeView(this, oEvent.getSource());
    },
[...]
```

And my NavigationBar.js:

```
function changeView(controller, source) {
var items = source.getParent().getItems();
console.log(items);
for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    items[i].getBindingContext().removeStyleClass("selectedNavItem");
}
source.addStyleClass("selectedNavItem");
[...]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither

`items[i].getBindingContext().removeStyleClass("selectedNavItem");`

nor

`items[i].removeStyleClass("selectedNavItem");`

will work.

The *ContextBinding* is a specific to binding context of object
, it does not have anything to do with *look n feel* of control.

Also, `removeStyleClass` is not available for [`NavigationListItem`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.tnt.NavigationListItem.html), as `removeStyleClass` is not available in any of it's ancestors; If you look at it's hierarchy it goes like `Element> Item> NavigationListItem`.

[`removeStyleClass`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#removeStyleClass) is only availble for controls that extend [`Control`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html) class

Comment: Thanks, that's the explanation I needed!

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using databinding to create the NavigationListItems, the items don't have a BindingContext. Even if they had one, the BindingContext doesn't control the styles of the Control. Something like this should work in your case:

```
items[i].removeStyleClass("selectedNavItem");
```